# Recaptch2 Remember Me functionality?

Tags: recaptcha

Is there any way to configure Google's Recaptcha 2 so that when the user closes their browser and then reopens it, they do not have to perform the recaptcha over again?

Is there a cookie or flag that can be set that allows the user to bypass the recaptcha check for say a week after a successful login/pass of the recaptcha check?

Answer (score 0):

No there is no such functionality. But that is somewhat similar to what invisible recaptcha does. This is new recaptcha mode, where, by running some advanced risk analysis algorithm, if user is determined not to be a bot, recaptcha automatically validates the user, and user never sees the challenge.

A side note: if you decide to play around with invisible recaptcha, you will see a challenge each time if you are testing it on your "localhost" server, but a live site, it only shows challenges to user if they are not verified yet.